# AWS RDS ssl connection from jdbc

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

Can I have encrypted jdbc connection without passing the certificate to the driver? I’m using spring boot application.

Comment: No. As documented if you want to enable  SSL/TLS connections you need to add the AWS RDS to the JDK cert store or load it in at runtime

Comment: @DarrenForsythe please link to this documentation you are citing. In my experience you can configure the JDBC driver to skip certificate validation if you just want an SSL connection without full validation. This may depend on the specific JDBC driver being used though, which needs to be added to the details of the question.